# Would a razor that doesn’t touch the skin be permissible?

Tags: halacha, minhag, shaving

I have seen Gillette has come out with a new razor that has as they call it a skin guard  [Skin Guard Razor](https://gillette.com/en-us/products/razors-trimmers-and-blades/skinguard-sensitive-skin-razor) in essence there is a piece of plastic between your face and the blade thus the shave is not as close and you are not dragging a razor across your face. Would this be Halachically permissible?

https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/1150-shaving/

https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shaving

Comment: How is this different from an electric shaver in terms of how the blade interacts with the hair follicle?

Comment: @DonielF an electric shaver users a scissor like motion trapping the hair between the foil and the blade where as this uses a razor motion of just cutting through the hair with the blade

Comment: What part of the hair? You say that it’s above the skin - does it pull the hair out of the surface of the skin in the process? (Please make sure to [edit] all relevant information into the post of itself - not in comments which might be deleted or in links which might be taken down.)

Comment: @DonielF I provide a link in the question to the razor. in every sense it is a conventional razor aside from it having a plastic guard over the blade.

Comment: @DonielF given that it functions as a regular razor I am to assume that there is no pulling involved more so the hair is cut similar to a scythe cutting wheat across a field. Thus the hair is left in tact after the cutting process not uprooted from the skin

Comment: In view of the last comment, esp., I'm not sure whether OP or @DonielF could best edit in something that briefly explains the halachic concern involved in this question. I think that would assist readers' understanding.

Comment: VTC b/c of "psak"? Why?

Comment: @DanF the halachic concern is the prohibition against shaving with a razor based on the closeness of the shave as well as the method by which the hair is cut

Comment: That description still seems too vague. "Closeness" is really vague - how close? My Norelco has various "closeness" settings. I think it's fake, but, that may be my own opinion or the way I'm using it. Also, which method do you mean? What does a razor do that an electric shaver does differently, in terms of making the razor forbidden?

Comment: @DanF an electric razor cuts the hair using a scissor like motion as opposed to being scraped across the face and cutting the hair. Closeness refers to how much of the hair is left after the razor cuts.

Comment: @DanF is there any halachic prohibition that you could see that would forbid me from using the razor mentioned above?

Comment: OK. Maybe edit a bit of those ideas into the question. I'm still not understanding exactly what the real halachic problem is. Is it the way it is cut (I don't think so, b/c burning all the hair off the skin seems to be fine - maybe not?) or is it a concern for not cutting the hair past a certain point (say, halachically, one must leave at least a micrometer of hair on the face.)

Comment: @DanF I added in some links from halachapedia and the OU but I essence I do not have the knowledge to decipher which Halacha in particular would be concerning this issue and if I would be violating them. My concern is would one be doing an Aveirah if they used this razor?